# How to increase a key value with +=

Tags: ruby, methods, hash, key-value

So I have a csv file that I'm pulling from and I'm having trouble figuring out how to increase the value of a key in one of my hashes. I keep getting the following error, any idea what the problem is? I've used similar syntax in other programs and haven't had any trouble:

```
rfiv.rb:39:in `block in get_order_num_bags': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

My csv file looks like this:
Type,SKU,RetailPrice,PurchasingPrice
Light,1111,5.00,1.50
Medium,2222,7.50,2.25
Bold,3333,9.75,2.95

And the ruby file I'm running looks like this:

```
require 'pry'
require 'csv'


@sku_key_menu = Hash.new

CSV.foreach('csvproducts.csv', headers: true) do |row|
  @sku_key_menu[row['SKU']] = {"Type" => row['Name'], "RetailPrice" => row['RetailPrice'], "PurchasingPrice" => row['PurchasingPrice']}
end

@sku_key_menu

def register_display(sku_key_menu) 
  sku_key_menu.each do |sku_key, product_desc_hash|
    puts " #{sku_key} - #{product_desc_hash["Type"]} - $#{product_desc_hash["RetailPrice"]}"
  end
end

register_display(@sku_key_menu) 



def get_order_num_bags
  @single_order = Hash.new(0)
  loop do
    puts "Please enter an SKU or type 'done' to complete order."
    @order_item = gets.chomp.to_s.downcase
    if @sku_key_menu.keys.include?(@order_item) || @order_item == "done"
      break if @order_item == "done"
      puts "Please enter the number of #{@order_item} that you'd like"
      number_of_bags = gets.chomp
      number_of_bags_valid = !!number_of_bags.to_s.match(/\A\d+(\.\d{2})?\z/)
      if number_of_bags_valid
        @single_order[@order_item] = @sku_key_menu[@order_item]
        @single_order[@order_item]['num_bags'] += number_of_bags.to_i  
      else
        puts "Invalid input"
      end
    else
      puts "Invalid input"
    end
  end
  puts @single_order
end

get_order_num_bags
```

Comment: `@single_order[@order_item]['num_bags']` is nil.

Answer (score 2):

`@single_order[@order_item]['num_bags']` is nil, so you can't add anything to it.

One solution is:

```
@single_order[@order_item]['num_bags'] ||= 0
@single_order[@order_item]['num_bags'] += number_of_bags.to_i
```

The `||= 0` is a common ruby technique for initializing a value.

An alternate solution is to initialize 'num_bags' when you are reading from the CSV file:

```
CSV.foreach('csvproducts.csv', headers: true) do |row|
  @sku_key_menu[row['SKU']] = {"Type" => row['Name'], "RetailPrice" => row['RetailPrice'], "PurchasingPrice" => row['PurchasingPrice'],
    'num_bags' => 0}
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @Matt. I'm now getting another error though:
fiv.rb:32:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError). Any thoughts?

Comment: Assuming you haven't added any other significant code to what's in your original post, one thought is that somehow `@single_order[@order_item]` is an Array instead of a Hash. So `@single_order[@order_item]['num_bags']` is trying to access an Array with a string 'num_bags' which could give that error. But I don't see how that could happen with the above code. Try outputting the value of `@sku_key_menu[@order_item]` to see what it is just before the error (or whatever would be relevant if your code has since changed.)

Comment: thanks for your help. The value from single_order[order_item] checked out. I made the following changes:
sku_key_menu = Hash.new(0)
single_order = Hash.new(0)

Comment: initializing was def part of the problem. Had to fix it like so:
Hash.new{ |hash, key| hash[key] = {} }